# Handlemessage(cMessage *msg) is not properly scheduled

Tags: omnet++

This is an example of omnet++ manual in chapter 4 , article 4.10.

Inside the `handleMessage` method the `msg` is not properly scheduled, I guess. In `case FSM_Exit(active):` state the error message shown. But how could the message be other than `startstopburst` and `sendmessage`?

```
void wirelessnode::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
FSM_Switch(fsm)
        {
        case FSM_Exit(init):
            FSM_Goto(fsm,sleep);
           break;
    case FSM_Enter(sleep):
            scheduleAt(simTime()+exponential(sleepTimeMean),startstop);
            break;
    case FSM_Exit(sleep):
            scheduleAt(simTime()+exponential(burstTimeMean),startstop);
    if(msg!=startstop)
    {
        error("Invalid event in state ACTIVE in FSM_Exit(sleep) state ");
    }
    FSM_Goto(fsm,active);
    break;
    case FSM_Enter(active):
            scheduleAt(simTime()+exponential(sendIATime),sendmsg);
    break;
    case FSM_Exit(active):
            if(msg==sendmsg)
            {
                FSM_Goto(fsm,snd);
            }
            else if(msg==startstop)
            {
                cancelEvent(sendmsg);
                FSM_Goto(fsm,sleep);
            }
            else
            {   
                error("invalid event in state ACTIVE in FSM_Exit(active) state ");
                //FSM_Goto(fsm,active);
             }
     break;
    case FSM_Exit(snd):
        {
        char msgname[32];
        sprintf(msgname,"job-%d",++i);
        ev <<"Generating"<< msgname <<endl;
        cMessage *job=new cMessage(msgname);
    //    job->SetBitLength ( (long) *msglength );
        job->setTimestamp();
        int gateCount=this->gateSize("radioInOut$o");
        int d=intrand(gateCount);
        send(job,"radioInOut$o",d);
        FSM_Goto(fsm,active);
    break;
          }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the code considers an event other than `startstopburst` and `sendmessage`, does not necessarily mean that there is another event, but there could be one.

In general, in a finite state machine you would like to consider all of the *allowed* and *disallowed* cases to avoid any undefined behavior. And what you see in the code is probably a measure against that.

On another note, if you view it in terms of coding -- whenever you have a `if` you better have an `else`

---

From the Wikipedia article about Finite-State Machine:

> ... It is conceived as an abstract machine **that can be in one of a
>   finite number of states.**

This means that all of the possible states should be defined (i.e. at any time the program must be in a well-defined state).

Comment: Would you please tell me the right sequence of code or incorrect point of code?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the code sequence

Comment: so why it detects an error "invalid event in state ACTIVE in FSM_Exit(active) state ".<br> did you run the code in your system ? <br> how could the msg be neither startstop nor sendmsg ?